# Virus lineage, strain, and relation to spike protein variants

Tags: virology, coronavirus

On the [CDC website](https://www.cdc.gov/coronavirus/2019-ncov/variants/variant-info.html) we have virus lineage which appears to be constant for all cases presented, or am I reading that wrong? Then the different names and of those with different names, different spike proteins can be associated. Then in these two papers authors use the word strain and describe as so:
[paper a](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-80464-1))
SARS-CoV-2/human/Liverpool/REMRQ0001/2020
where they mention that they *also* test the D614G variant of the spike

[paper b](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41392-020-00426-x))
BetaCov/human/CHN/Beijing_IME-BJ05/2020
BetaCoV/Wuhan/IVDC-HB-01/2020|EPI_ISL_402119

How do I use the species information to determine what spike variants were used in the studies?

Comment: You can trace the first one back to the [original paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7602519/). In general though, if you want to check specific sequences, look for the Genbank numbers, have a look on [VIPRBRC](https://www.viprbrc.org/) and/or get a [GISAID](https://www.gisaid.org/) login (I think you need affiliation with a recognized organisation for this one). GISAID generally has the most sequences, but I'm too lazy to dig out my login and tell you if these ones are deposited. That being said that last one certainly is as the EPI_ISL # is GISAID format

Comment: Thank you, bob1. I am wondering whether the discrepancy in the results between paper a and paper b could be attributed to a variance in the spike protein, that's why I'm looking into this. Also, if this not out to not be the reason for the discrepancy, would the use of the pseudovirus in paper b potentially provide an explanation?

Comment: It is possible that it is the variant. For the last part, you should post it  as another question.